# How to train a CNN model on multiple CSV files?

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset containing thermal images saved as csv files of temperature value (I have 2300 csv files for 3 classes, a file csv have 640 columns and 512 rows). I want to use this data to train a CNN model but I don't know how to import these csv files to train. I used `pd.read_csv("file1.csv")` to read csv file.
Here is an example of data:
CSV file:
[Here is the complete CSV file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l7V_FOFLUQI6R6XWOiVgwpVovGqbp3bA/view?usp=sharing)

a part of csv file:

[image]

and the thermal image (image size is 640x512):

[image]

I am a bit confused about what exactly should I even google search for this. Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for having these iamges as csv files?

Comment: Hi Giorgos Livanos, I use csv data as input instead of using image because I want to use csv to compare the output when using csv and image.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a sample generator that yields a pandas'  CSV reading and then use the `tf.data.Dataset API` to handle it. Using `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` you can pass a `tf.TensorSpec` to describe your data and then add a channel dimension in order to be compatible with convolutional layers. Here is a minimal example with the provided image and the output:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

def example_generator():
    files = ['file1.csv']
    for i in files:
        yield pd.read_csv(i, header=None)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(generator=example_generator, output_signature=tf.TensorSpec(shape=(512, 640), dtype=tf.float32))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.expand_dims(x, -1))  # Add channel dimension

for i in dataset.as_numpy_iterator():
    print(i.shape)
    cv2.imshow('', i/i.max())
    cv2.waitKey()


Output: (512, 640, 1)
```

[image: Result from provided image.]